# Passportsjs logout - document says to use app.post but fails saying "Cannot GET /logout"

Tags: passport.js

The documentation for passport js https://www.passportjs.org/concepts/authentication/logout/ says..."It is a good idea to use POST or DELETE requests instead of GET requests for the logout endpoints, in order to prevent accidental or malicious logouts."

My code looks like this...

```
app.post('/logout', function(req, res){
  req.logout(function(err) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});
```

The error I get when logging out is "Cannot GET /logout"

when I change the app.post to app.get it works no problem but that goes against what the documentation is suggesting.  How do I get app.post to work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to move that "logout button or link" inside your .ejs and put it inside a form, so you would be able to post that logout request.

Something like this:

```
<form class="" action="/logout" method="post">
<button class="" type="submit" name="button">Logout</button>
</form>
```

Share the code where you put the option for the user to logout and i will help with that too.